# What causes equipartition of energy to break down?

Tags: thermodynamics

While reading up equipartition of energy I found that a graph of specific heat capacity against temperature can show changes in s.h.c. at those points where the rotational or vibrational modes are 'frozen out'. Is the explanation for this simply that it's not possible for the modes to share their energy eg below some temperature  translational energy stops being converted into rotational? I appreciate this is a quantum effect but, correct me if I'm wrong, the quantization of energy by itself wouldn't explain it. What's special about the translational modes that they might be the ones that rarely get frozen out?
This page for example  us that the rotational modes of nitrogen begin to 'unfreeze' above 300 celsius.: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity

Answer (score 1):

Translational modes typically have a continuous spectrum, so that their states with non-zero energy are populated at very low temperature. On the other hand, rotational and vibration modes have discrete states. E.g., a vibrational mode can be viewed as a harmonic oscillator with frequency $\omega$ and energies
$$
E_n=\hbar\omega(n+\frac{1}{2}).
$$
as long as $$k_BT\ll \hbar\omega$$ only the ground state of this oscillator is occupied, and the mode can be considered "frozen".

Comment: Many thanks, very neat! If it's the case that, as temperature is reduced, the vibrational modes are frozen out before (ie at a higher temperature than) the rotational ones, do we conclude that the quantization of the vibrational mode is bigger than the rotational? What theoretical method would we use to estimate the size of the rotational quanta?

Comment: @DRBall You can estimate the rotational quanta from the molecular moment of inertia. See [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/516110/molecular-rotational-energies-and-frequencies-of-diatomic-molecule).